# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sequence_next_hi_value' in 'field list

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

Anybody can tell what cause this error?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Unknown column 'sequence_next_hi_value' in 'field list
```

I am connecting to a `mysql` database using `hibernate`. I was able to connect to the database and everything was working fine till I change the `persistence.xml` and added a `datasource`.

Comment: it means that this column `sequence_next_hi_value` was not found. it maybe because of your joins, (*hard to tell*). can you post your query?

Comment: Most likely you are running a query on a table that does not contain a column named `sequence_next_hi_value`

Comment: Could you post some of the coding?

Comment: Yes you are all right, this cloumn doesn exist. Thing is that it wasnt me that generated this column. Somehow it was auto-generated. It crashes only when I try an "insert" query. I think it has to do with the primary key. I m using the strategy=GenerationType.TABLE.
What piece of code would it be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the used identifier generation type for your entities.

Make sure you've provided following annotations and parameters:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="name_of_the_generator")
@TableGenerator( name = "name_of_the_generator", table = "table_with_keys", pkColumnName = "PK_NAME", valueColumnName = "PK_VALUE")
```

My guess is  that you have mixed **valueColumnName** with **pkColumnValue**.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem , my solution is change GenerationType from `@GeneratedValue` strategy on Primary Keys to `GenerationType.IDENTITY` on hibernate 5 and MySQL as DB